# Theme Customizer performance drops when adding a lot of settings

Tags: theme-customizer, settings-api

I maintain a plugin in which we currently add ~730 settings to the Theme Customizer. We use a few custom controls for panels, sections and settings and loading the preview is a very painful experience since the page can take between 15 and 60 seconds to load, depending on the server. When using the refresh transport method, changing a setting will cause another wait for 3-10 seconds, again depending on the server. Thats why for one thing I plan to migrate to the postMessage transpor method.

However, this seems to be a bit abnormal in general to me so I created a very simple plugin that only adds 750 text field settings and even this super simple thing will drastically increase the loading time of the theme customizer:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Test
*/

add_action('customize_register', function ($wp_customize) {
    $panels = 5;
    $sections = 5;
    $settings = 30;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $panels; $i++) {
        $wp_customize->add_panel("test_{$i}", array(
            'title' => "test_{$i}",
            'description' => 'Lorem Ipsum',
        ));
    
        for ($j = 1; $j <= $sections; $j++) {
            $wp_customize->add_section("test_{$i}_{$j}", array(
                'title' => "test_{$i}_{$j}",
                'panel' => "test_{$i}",
            )); 

            for ($k = 1; $k <= $settings; $k++) {
                $wp_customize->add_setting("test_{$i}_{$j}_{$k}", [
                    'type' => 'option',
                    'capability' => 'manage_options',
                    'default' => 'test',
                ]);
            
                $wp_customize->add_control(new \WP_Customize_Upload_Control($wp_customize, "test_{$i}_{$j}_{$k}", [
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'section' => "test_{$i}_{$j}",
                    'settings' => "test_{$i}_{$j}_{$k}",
                    'label' => "Test {$i}_{$j}_{$k}",
                    'description' => 'Lorem Ipsum',
                ]));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Now I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong or if this is simply how WordPress implements it. Maybe the Theme Customizer is not made to have hundreds or even thousands of settings in it.

Has anybody any idea on how to improve the loading speed of the customizer using the code above as a baseline?

Comment: Without knowing exactly what these settings are it’s hard to suggest an alternative, but I feel pretty comfortable saying that the Customiser simply isn’t built for that many controls. Why do you need so many settings? If you’re trying to give full control over fine details of a theme then I would look at FSE and block themes, as that’s the direction WordPress is going for that sort of thing.

Comment: 700+ is a lot!! What are these controls doing that requires 700+? There's also no code in your question, so it's very difficult to advise. Also keep in mind that this isn't a discussion forum, you need to ask your question in such a way that someone can write a specific/factual answer that works for all people with this question, not just you, that you can mark as the correct answer, not just the best.

Comment: In our plugin we add functionality to WordPress and the Divi theme. For example the user can add a CTA Button in the menu and then use the Customizer to style this button, e. g. background color, padding, margin, font, etc.

Back then we chose the Customizer so users can preview their changes because our plugin is for beginners who are not experienced with CSS. Thats why the user should get a WYSIWYG experience. 

I added sample code and changed my question slightly. I'm afraid though that since our plugin depends on the Divi theme being active, FSE and block themes are not an option.